# Taylor series question

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I've been struggling with this problem:

Find the Taylor series representation for  $xe^{2x}$

I was able to find the Taylor series for $e^{2x}$ (centered at a=k) in a previous exercise which I found to be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^ne^{2k}(x-k)^n}{n!}$

I've looked on wolfram alpha and the answer seems to be $x{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^ne^{2k}(x-k)^n}{n!}}$

I just don't know if that's right and if so, how to arrive at that conclusion. 
There is no grade associated with this. It's a practice exercise and it's been a while since I've had to use Taylor series so it's infuriating me that I can't figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Multiply $x$ to the series you've already found, no? Seems like that's the answer WA is suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You may just write
$$
xe^{2x}=(x-k)\times\color{blue}{e^{2x}}+k\times\color{blue}{e^{2x}}\tag1
$$ then insert
$$
\color{blue}{e^{2x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^ne^{2k}(x-k)^n}{n!}\tag2
$$ in $(1)$.

Comment: What's the point? Couldn't you just substitute expansion for $e^{2x}$ directly to the $x e^{2x}$?

Comment: @Kaster The Taylor series is at $x=k$ not at $x=0$...

Comment: @Olivier Oloa Thank you very much for your response I only have one question: what made you arrive at that idea?

Comment: @WhatsAGuitar It is because you need to make that $x$ has a *Taylor series expansion form*, then you write $x=(x-k)+k$. Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierOloa what makes you think that
$$
x \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac {2^n e^{2k}(x - k)^n}{n!}
$$
isn't Taylor series expansion at the point $x = k$?

Comment: @Kaster Because a Taylor series at $x=k$ has to be of the form $$  \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}(x - k)^n$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa I appreciate the help you've provided. I just think I'm experiencing some confusion: doesn't your proposition just simplify to what Wolfram Alpha and Kaster have stated?

Comment: @WhatsAGuitar No. You should rather end up with $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+2)2^{n-1}e^{2k}(x-k)^n}{n!}. $$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you very much for your help. I'll see if my algebra will allow me to arrive at that answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @WhatsAGuitar You are welcome!

Comment: @OlivierOloa is that expansion you provided for $xe^{2x}$ or $(x-k)e^{2x}$?

Comment: @WhatsAGuitar Sorry, typo fixed, the correct answer is $$xe^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+2k)2^{n-1}e^{2k}(x-k)^n}{n!}. $$

Comment: @Kaster Yes, but more importantly the terms of the Taylor series are only of the form $\text{something} \times (x-k)^{n}$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa thank you very much!